# MongoDB query the same table as alias

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection "details".

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("50e876e49d5d0cbc08000001"),
   "user_id": "50e876e49d5d0cbc08000000",
   "left": NumberInt(1),
   "right": NumberInt(2)
}   
{
   "_id": ObjectId("50e876b79d5d0c040a000001"),
   "user_id": "50e876b79d5d0c040a000000",
   "left": NumberInt(3),
   "right": NumberInt(4)
}
```

I would like to write a query in MongoDB which is similar in SQL as under:

```
SELECT node.user_id
FROM details AS node,
        details AS parent
WHERE node.left BETWEEN parent.left AND parent.right
       AND parent.user_id = "50e876e49d5d0cbc08000000"
ORDER BY node.left;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Start with the [SQL comparison](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) and [SQL to Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)

Comment: Why can't you query for `parent` first and then use it to query for everything else?

Comment: tried find and aggregation...did not work... I also need this to run from PHP-lithium framework!

Comment: @Leonid, can you give me some hint... "details" is the same collection for node and parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for parent first and then use it to query for everything else:

```
parent = db.details.findOne({user_id: ObjectId("50e876e49d5d0cbc08000000")});
query = {left: {$gt: parent.left, $lt: parent.right}};
select = {user_id: 1};
db.details.find(query,select).sort({left: 1})
```

Replace `$gt` and `$lt` with `$gte` and `$lte` if you want to query for "greater then or equal to" and "lesser then or equal to" instead of "greater then" and "lesser then".